# ByRef argument does not work as expected

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Anyone ever see this?

```
Public Shared Function IsAvailableByCampaignId(ByVal cn As SqlConnection, ByVal tr As SqlTransaction, ByVal campaignId As Integer, ByRef dest As PricingThresholds) As Boolean
    Dim retObj = ItemTypes.PricingThresholds.GetThresholds(cn, tr, campaignId)
    If retObj IsNot Nothing Then
        dest = New PricingThresholds(retObj)
    End If
    Dim retVal As Boolean = retObj IsNot Nothing
    Return retVal
End Function
```

When I make the call to the inner

`Dim retObj = ItemTypes.PricingThresholds.GetThresholds(cn, tr, campaignId)`

I get a non-null or nothing retObj, but then I use it to build a new PricingThresholds with it that is the right type that I need to return, and am successful at creating a valid return type object but I get back from the outer call the parm dest the is passed `ByRef` has no value and is nothing or null.

It's like VB isn't working.

I suppose I can just return it a different way.

Comment: VB.NET is working, your code is not doing the right things. Can you also show us where and how you are calling this function? The problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

Below code shows that everything is working as expected, i.e. `dest` is being reassigned, and keeps its value outside of `IsAvailableByCampaignId` function:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim dest As New PricingThresholds(1)
  Dim p = IsAvailableByCampaignId(dest)
End Sub

Class PricingThresholds
  Dim _id As Integer
  Sub New(id As Integer)
    _id = id
  End Sub
End Class

Public Function IsAvailableByCampaignId(ByRef dest As PricingThresholds) As Boolean
  dest = New PricingThresholds(2)
  Return True
End Function
```

Feel free to play with this code, and see if you can reproduce the bevahior you are having.